# Run clickonce application in pendrive without user click

Tags: clickonce, usb-drive

How to run the clickonce application from USB device on inserting without any user click ?
Not only for a particular users PC,i want to run it for all users PC.Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any way to do this without any clicks. At the very least, Windows would come up and ask what they want to do with the device, right?

If you could do this, you could write a virus and infest someone's computer simply by plugging a USB drive into it. Doesn't seem like an optimal scenario to me.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible by changing some driver inside USB, So that USB will appear as CD in PC and Autorun will work as in CD.
This is the way USB dongle's are working nowadays